# Draw lines as a cross hair in an existing NSImage

Tags: iphone, macos, graphics

I been on the computer the whole day trying to figure out how to draw some lines on an
existing NSImage.

It got it working but the code I have uses

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

Where the downside is that I have to know the number of bits in the image, so what happens is that the resulting bitmap does sometimes have a lower image quality than the original NSImage.

What is the easiest/fastest way to simply draw lines directly onto an NSImage?

It would be nice if the code was compatible with both Mac OSX and iOS.

Comment: What are you doing with the images? Saving them to disk or simply displaying them on screen?

Comment: displaying them on the screen

Comment: Then why not simply display an image of a cross hair above your original image using two different image views? Alternatively you could draw the cross hair above the image in the `drawRect` of a custom view. Would that work for you?

Comment: No I have to draw it directly to the image for other reasons.

Answer (score 4):

NSImage doesn't exist on iOS, so the code will have to be different. It's fairly easy to draw on a NSImage.

Example:

```
- (void)drawCrosshair:(NSImage*)img
{
    [img lockFocus];

    NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(90,100)];
    [path lineToPoint:CGPointMake(110,100)];

    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100,90)];
    [path lineToPoint:CGPointMake(100,110)];

    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    [path stroke];
    [img unlockFocus];
}
```